# How to remove the comma(,) from the first position and last position of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove the comma(,) from the the string if it occur at first position or last position in the string.

For Example :

```
 var str = ",abcd,efg,last,";
```

The output should be

```
output = 'abcd,efg,last'
```

if input is

```
str = "abcdef,ghij,kl"
```

the output should be :

```
output = "abcdef,ghij,kl"
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var str = ",abcd,efg,last,";
var res = str.replace(/^,|,$/g, '');
console.log(res);
```

do this

this will remove the comma if it is at the starting position `or` at the end of the string position

Answer (score 0):

There must be some strip() function in Javascript that I don't know for lack of my knowledge. But here is how you can do it using regex:

```
 output = ",abcd,efg,last,".replace(/^,|,$/g, "");
```

Comment: _JavaScript_ has `String.prototype.trim` but it takes no args :( (I think it should take a _String_ of blacklisted characters.. maybe I'll even put that as an answer)

Answer (score 0):

*JavaScript* doesn't include a native method for this. The closest is `trim`, but that doesn't take any args. I think it should, though. So you could write something like this

```
String.prototype.trim = (function (trim) {
    if (!trim) // polyfill if not included in browser
        trim = function () {
            return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
        };
    else if (trim.call('.', '.') === '') // already supports this
        return trim;
    return function (chars) {
        if (!chars) return trim.call(this);
        chars = chars.replace(/([\^\\\]-])/g, '\\$1');
        return this.replace(new RegExp('^['+chars+']+|['+chars+']+$', 'g'), '');
    }
}(String.prototype.trim));
```

Now we have

```
'   foo   '.trim();    // "foo"
',,,foo,,,'.trim(','); // "foo"
```